# Jquery scripts overriding kendo scripts in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

In My project i am using kendo controls for that am using kendo scripts
before using jquery popup all my project works well .
After adding the jquery scripts .AM getting error

Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoMenu'

if i didn't include Jquery scripts .dialog extension method not coming.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.common.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.default.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.black.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css")">

@* <link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<link href="@Url.Content("~/ext/kendo.ext.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/kendo.timezones.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/console.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/prettify.min.js")"></script>

@* <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ext/kendo.web.ext.js")"></script>
```

I want to use jquery popup for that i used following scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

before using jquery popup all my project works well .
After adding the jquery scripts .AM getting error

Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoMenu'

if i didn't include Jquery scripts .dialog extension method not coming.

How can i solve these issue plz suggest me.

Comment: put all jquery reference scripts at the top..

Comment: and also remove multiple reference to jquery library..

Answer (score 1):

You need only one jQuery library on the page. Check this **[article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/troubleshooting#javascript-error-that-kendo-widgets-are-unavailable-or-undefined)**.